How are potentiostats calibrated in practice?
I've been thinking about calibrating a custom made potentiostat (essentially a multi-frequency impedance meter) that measures impedance of the test object under multiple frequencies with a four-terminal connection. The frequency range of tests are generally within 0.01 Hz to 10 kHz and the impedance of the test object is generally within the \$\mu\Omega\$ to \$m\Omega\$ range.
However, in order to calibrate this, I need to create calibration standards with known impeadnce values. But this calls for the need of an accurate potentiostat that can measure the true value of the calibration standards, which becomes a chicken-and-egg problem.
Based on some research, it seems that a few commercial manufacturers use PCB type of standards, where resistors, sometimes with capacitors, with known values are used.
My question is, if I build a PCB with resistors and capacitors, can I assume the parasitics of the components themselves and inductance of the PCB traces are sufficiently small that I can regard the nominal impedance of the PCB as its real impedance for calibration purposes?
Or a better question may be how is this problem solved in practice?

Select high-quality resistors like thin-film or metal-film resistors with low-temperature coefficients.

Impedance of the test object is generally within μΩ to mΩ range? What is the value of the current flowing through this low resistance? Do you have a diagram of your potentiostat?

First of all, it's not clear whether you are talking about a potentiostat (an instrument used in electrochemistry in a way I do not fully understand) and an impedance meter (an instrument used to measure two-terminal impedances, possibly with four-terminal connection).
Secondly, you need to specify the frequency and impedance (both real and imaginary) range you are interested in. AND the degree of accuracy sought, AND whether you want the measurements to be traceable to standards.
In general- well-chosen resistors have small parasitic capacitance (and inductance) and small-valued ones will behave like pure resistances at low enough frequency. Capacitors will have well-specified loss and again when suitably chosen the loss can be negligible. Although the value tolerance of capacitors is usually large. For impedance meter calibration you can buy standards- I used to have an HP 1K or 10K ohm 4-terminal standard.
AND at high frequency there are of course commercial short open match thru standards.

Hi thanks for pointing these out! I've edited the question to include more info.

At those frequencies and impedance magnitudes you can totally neglect stray capacitance and inductance. It will, however, be essential to properly connect 4 terminals to reject series resistance. A resistance standard can be as simple as a length of wire or PCB trace (again, with proper voltage leads and current connection). The resistance can be very accurately determined with a DVM at DC. For capacitance- I seem to remember electrochemical guys doing Cole-Cole plots where real and imaginary parts were comparable. To get a milliohm reactance at 1 Hz requires around a hundred microfarads. This can be bought as a mylar or similar low- loss capacitor (NOT under any circumstances electrolytic, since and electrolytic is an electrochemical experiment by itself). Of course the tolerance will be high- I don't think you can do better than +/- 5%.
